# How to create an instance of two classes at the same time?

Tags: delphi, class

This is my problem - shortly:

```
var c1:TClass1;
c2:TClass2;
begin
  c1 := c1.Create;
  c2 := c2.Create; //<<Exception;
end;
```

Both classes inherit from TObject.If they don't inherit then I can't use the debugger in the class so I have to use TObject.

My real problem is that I have to create the instance of the second class inside a function in the instance of the first class.I can't find a way to free the instance of the first class while i'm inside it.

It seems I can't have more than one class that inherits from TObject,is that the problem?

How do I fix my code,any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Didn't the compiler give you a warning about a variable or two being undefined?

Comment: "It seems I can't have more than one class that inherits from TObject,is that the problem?" No, the VCL alone has hundreds of classes inheriting from TObject. "If they don't inherit then I can't use the debugger in the class so I have to use TObject." Don't guess or fantasize, try to make sense of the compiler output and fix any hints and warnings first. The debugger has no place at all in finding problems in simple code snippets like yours.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proper syntax should be:

```
C1 := TClass1.Create;
C2 := TClass2.Create;
```

Comment: Indeed. The question is not about creating two instances at the same time. It's about managing to create any instance at all.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on skamradt's answer:

You are attempting to use your classes before creating them.  Internally, classes are pointers to the data in the class.  Thus you are dereferencing an unassigned pointer.  Is it any wonder your code goes boom?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that constructors do two jobs.

```
var c1: TClass1;
c1 := TClass1.Create;
```

will construct a new instance of type TClass1, while

```
c1.Create;
```

will *re-initialise* c1 - all the statements in the constructor will execute, but the constructor won't return a new instance.